# Good source of Buddha stories and what they mean

Tags: texts

Try again.

I have an idea for a comic book I would like to attempt.  It is based in a contemporary setting and sort of outlines the principles of buddhism without actually comingout and saying so.

What I am after is a good source of Buddha stories and what they mean.  You know the sort of thing, Buddha said this or did that and what he was getting at.

I had a book by Suzuki once that was full of them but I am sure there is a website whith some somewhere.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. What exactly is your question about Buddhism? A comic? Contemporary?

Comment: Are you trying to draw comics depicting stories from the Buddha's life or past lives? How would that be contemporary?

Comment: It wouldn't be about Buddha but it would touch on some Buddhist principles.  Think contemporary re-interpretation of Shakespeare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for "Zen Flesh, Zen Bones" in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Please see Buddhanet's [Buddhist Studies eBook Library](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/ebooks.htm).

It contains ebooks on the Buddha's life story, Jataka tales, stories of his disciples, stories from the Dhammapada commentary and other suttas.

Comment: That's a great resource. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid to dive into the deep end, then you could start with the [Jataka Tales.](https://www.pitt.edu/%7Edash/jataka.html) I haven't got the time to compile my own description, so I've pulled this wiki.

> The Jataka tales are a voluminous body of literature native to India concerning the previous births of Gautama Buddha in both human and animal form. The future Buddha may appear as a king, an outcast, a god, an elephant—but, in whatever form, he exhibits some virtue that the tale thereby inculcates.

Comment: Yes, that sort of thing.

Comment: @ThirdPrize - The link I provided will take you to some of those stories. Best wishes.